# PutExtras changing me the Date?

Tags: android, calendar, android-pendingintent

I have a `Service` that creates a `Notification`, in which the Date is passed, as a `String`, through `putExtra`, this way:

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();        
cal.set(2013, 3, 27);
Date d=new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());
SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String fechafinal=format.format(d);
Intent notIntent=new Intent(c, AlertsActivity.class);
notIntent.putExtra("fechafin",fechafinal);//Along with other values, I pass this one
PendingIntent contIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            c, 0, notIntent, 0);
Builder notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(c);
```

With a `Log.i`, I can see that there, the `fechafinal` value is set properly, with the correct value, it is, 27-04-2013. If I am correct, the `Activity` called when the users clicks the `Notification`, is `AlertsActivity`.

In `AlertsActivity class` (The piece that matters):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatofecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String fecha;
    bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
    fecha=formatofecha.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    String fechaFin;                        
    fechaFin=bundle.getString("fechafin");              
    Notificacion noti=new Notificacion(bundle.getString("nombre"),                                         bundle.getString("lugar"), 
fecha, 
fechaFin,
bundle.getString("dinero"),
                                       bundle.getBoolean("buzoneo"),
                                       bundle.getString("desc"),
                                       bundle.getString("labor"),
                                       bundle.getString("horainicio"),
                                       bundle.getString("horafin"));
```

PD: "Notificacion" is a class where I store the values that will be presented in a detailed view of some kind of job offer, it's not Notification's Android class.

If I put a `Log.i` here... I see that inside `fechafin` comes "2013/12/12", and I don't know why. it's driving me nuts!

Anybody has the same problem? Thank You!

Comment: Can you show your receiver class?

Comment: What do you mean receiver class? The receiver of the notification, AlertsActivity?

Comment: You are trying to set something like notifications at predefined times if I am not wrong and yes, I am asking about the broadcastreceiver.

Comment: Please, post the code where you are retrieving date from extras

Comment: birdy is chirping right..

Comment: Edited to show the code where I retrieve the data from extras. I don't  send a Date object, I send a String in the extras.

Comment: @Fustigador I think you get that 2013/12/12 for fecha variable, not a fechaFin. It can't change the string by itself which you kept in as extras.

Comment: But... fecha is another variable, i have put a Log.i there, fecha stores the today's date, and fechaFin the 2013/12/12. fecha is made from a Calendar object and fechaFin is entirely a String.

Comment: can't you use `String fechafinal = format.format(cal);` instead of wrapping it into another `Date` object?

Comment: Throws an IllegalArgumentException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, by doing simply this:

```
String fechafinal=format.format(d).toString();
```

Why if I Log.i it shows fine, and when assigned without the .toString() method it does not, it's beyond my comprehension.